# How much CPU is FFmpeg consuming?

Tags: linux, testing, ffmpeg, cpu

I want to find out how much CPU my FFmpeg process is consuming. Is there a parameter or implementation for this?

I have used various linux applications, but I did not understand anything clearly.

Comment: `top` can show you on the fly, `time ffmpeg ...` can show you overall.  `perf stat ffmpeg ...` can also give you stats, like CPU %, or attach it to a running `ffmpeg`.  None of this is specific to FFmepg.

Comment: @Zeki which programs have you tried?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the below commands to check how much cpu is used

```bash
top -i | grep ffmpeg
```

or

```bash
ps aux | grep [f]fmpeg
```

or use htop and press F3 or / and start typing in the process name to search.